# JQDateRangeSlider: get the new values after changing the bounds

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's the first time when I'm working with the JQDateRangeSlider, and I've been using it as a time slider: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dana15/LJrYf/150/)

After it changes the bounds pressing the 'Min' or 'Max' button, I should get the new bound min and max value:

```
values = $("#slider").dateRangeSlider('values');
var trail_time = '.' + ('00' + values.min.getHours()).slice(-2) + '.' + ('00' + values.min.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + '.' + ('00' + values.max.getHours()).slice(-2) + '.' + ('00' + values.max.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
```

but it returns the old values. After I try to change the bounds again I get the info that I should get on the first time, and on the third attempt I get the second answer.

Is there any chance to get the current values, not the previous ones?